# React Native app - missing Android Profiler tool in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-profiler

I want to measure my app perfomance in the way exactly the same as it is with standard Android app by using Android Profiler, but in this case there is no available Android Profiler tool for this React Native project. I typed 'profiler' in searching tool and it's now showing it up, as presented on screenshot below.

[image: Android Profiler not available]

I'am quite confused how to fix that issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `Profiler` option is not showing up, it may happen that you have not build your latest code yet. Just build your code then `Profile` option will show up in tab

Alternatively, you can start `Profile (Run)` option as you posted in screenshot. It will build for you

Comment: This should be actually marked as the correct answer.